# odbc_fetch_row doesn't work when it is used multiple times

Tags: php, odbc

```
while(odbc_fetch_row($viewTablo)){
    
          echo "<td>".odbc_result($viewTablo,$inta)."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";     
}
```

This code works and returns values I expected. But when I use `odbc_fetch_row` multiple times, just the first one works. What is the reason  and how do I prevent this?

Comment: It will only fetch as many rows as are present in your query results. Once you run out of rows, it won't return anything.

Comment: so I can't use 2 whiles on the same project , right?... @ADyson

Comment: That's right. If you want to loop over the data multiple times, put it all into a PHP array when you first extract it from the database, and then use the array later on in the script when you need to access it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will only fetch as many rows as are present in your query results. Once you run out of rows, it will return `false` as per the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-fetch-array.php). It does not return the result set's internal pointer to the beginning of the results.

If you want to loop over the data multiple times you can put it all into a PHP array when you first extract it from the database, and then use the array later on in the script when you need to access it.